# JPA conditional insertion / RDBMS Transactions isolation?

Tags: mysql, jpa, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

I want to insert a record to an RDBMS table only if the table does not consist of any rows which are "similar" (according to some specific, irrelevant criteria) to the said row. I have a simple SELECT query for checking if any "similar" rows exist.

I originally figured that to achieve my target, it'd be enough to run the SELECT query conditionally followed by the INSERT query, both together inside one transaction. However, I've been reading about different isolation levels, and it seems like in a concurrent environment, two threads might run the SELECT statement concurrently, and end up both inserting "similar" rows to the table, even though the SELECT+INSERT are in the same transaction.

First question: I'm using JPA (over Hibernate) and a MySQL DB (using InnoDB engine for all my tables). What is the best way to achieve my goal? I'd obviously rather stay standard, but am willing to go native if needed.

Second question: Assuming I don't mind "overriding" records with "similar" records, and I replace the SELECT statement with DELETE one - will it work as I intend it to then? Basically what I'm asking here is whether a DELETE+INSERT in one transaction is atomic, in the sense that if two threads run those simultaneously then no matter how they run, the table won't ever consist of both inserted entries after the two transactions are finished (On one hand, I'd be really surprised if it's not atomic in this sense, but on the other, it seems like this forces a table lock, doesn't it?).

Thank you for your help!